# Encontrar e mostrar um objeto de um .json pelo id do elemento clicado - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Como faço para procurar dentro de um json um objeto com um determinado `id`, esse processo deve ocorrer dentro de uma `function $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){});`, e o `id` a ser pesquisado vai ser o `id` do elemento `li` clicado, o resultado da pesquisa seria o retorno de todos os dados do elemento que possui o `id` do `li` clicado .

Bom acho que a explicação ta simples mas ta clara, desculpe eu não colocar código, na verdade eu quero ideias para que eu pesquise e aprende, se eu colocar o código aqui vou obter a resposta pronta, não é isso que eu quero, mas caso for necessário eu posto um código de exemplo aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saberes o ID do elemento clicado basta fazer `var id = this.id;`.

**Se o JSON for uma array:**

Neste caso tens de percorrer o array comparando o teu ID com a chave que precisas. No exemplo usei também a chave `id`. O `.find()` é util pois retorna o primeiro elemento da array que cumprir a verificação.

```
var json = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var obj = json.find(function(_obj){
        return _obj.id == id;
    });
    console.log(obj);
});
```

**Se o JSON for um Objeto:**

Neste caso imagino que queiras o sub-objeto e a coisa fica ainda mais simples.

```
var json = {id1: {foo: 'bar'}, id2: {foo: 'baz'}};
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var obj = json[id];
    console.log(obj);
});
```

---

Se esse JSON vier por exemplo por ajax podes fazer assim:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
    var id = this.id;
    $.getJSON("../file.json", function(json){
        // aqui podes usar um dos meus exemplos com Array ou Objeto
        // usando a variável "json" da callback

    }); 
});
```

Comment: tentei aqui mas ta me retornando `undefined` no console.

Comment: Consegui =D , o posicionamento de uma variavel minha estava errado. por isso estava dando indefinido.